# Data inserted in MYSQL DB from Node.js is undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I insert data into my DB it says that it was successful but upon checking my DB, all of my fields are null. I am getting undefined values on my firstName,lastName, mobile, and email columns.

I'm really having a hard time debugging as I'm pretty new to JS. I hope anyone can point out what's the problem.

This is the model for `Guest`

```
var Guest = function(guest) {
    this.firstName = guest.firstName;
    this.lastName = guest.lastName;
    this.mobile = guest.mobile;
    this.email = guest.email;
}

// Insert Guest Data to DB
Guest.createGuest = (guestRequestData, result) => {
    db.query('INSERT INTO guest SET ? ', guestRequestData, (error, response) => {
        if(error){
            console.log('Error while inserting data');
            result(null, error);
        }else{
            console.log('Guest created successfully');
            result(null, response);
        }
    })
}

module.exports = Guest;
```

And this the controller

```
// Create New Guest
exports.createNewGuest = (request, response) => {
    const guestRequestData = new GuestModel(request.body);
    console.log('Request Data', guestRequestData);
    // Check Null
    if(request.body.constructor === Object && Object(request.body).length === 0){
        response.send(400).send({success: false, message: 'Please fill all fields'});
    }else{
        GuestModel.createGuest(guestRequestData, (error, guest) => {
            if(error)
            response.send(error);
            response.json({status: true, message: 'Guest Created Successfully', data: guest.insertId})
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a clear example how to insert data into MySQL database using `node.js`: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/insert/

So in your case would look something like this:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO guest (firstName, lastName, mobile, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', guestRequestData, (error, response) => {
        if(error){
            console.log('Error while inserting data');
            result(null, error);
        }else{
            console.log('Guest created successfully');
            result(null, response);
        }
    })
```

where the `guestRequestData` has the following structure:

```
["Your first name", "Your last name", "Your mobile", "Your email"]
```

Make sure you convert the `guestRequestData` to this format.